# Desktop shortcut for running python Script

Tags: python-3.x, windows, miniconda

so far I'm running my python scripts by activating my virtual environment in Anaconda Prompt, opening Spyder and Running the script in Spyder. I would like to simply create Desktop Shortcut which will run my script. What is the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: Please add what OS you're using. From top of my head, I could say for `windows`, create a bat script with /virtual-env/Scripts/python.exe /my/path/to/script.py  (or) if `Linux` create an *.sh file to run it with same command

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install pyshortcuts`.  For more details on usage, see https://github.com/newville/pyshortcuts#pyshortcuts